# How to translate this 2 queries from Mysql to Postgresql? :

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

How can I translate this 2 queries in postgresql ? :

```
CREATE TABLE  `example` ( 
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,    
  `from` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '0',    
  `message` text NOT NULL,    
  `lastactivity` timestamp NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',    
  `read` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),    
  KEY `from` (`from`)    
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 ON ( table_1.id = table_2.id ) 
WHERE (table_1.lastactivity > NOW()-100);
```

Comment: There's only one 'query' though two SQL statements.  ISTM that your only real issue is 'How does NOW() - 100 in PostgreSQL map to MySQL' (unless your question is going the other way around - moving from MySQL to PostgreSQL).  If you are going to PostgreSQL, you're likely to need to use SQL standard delimited identifiers in double quotes `"from"` instead of the MySQL deviation-from-standard with back-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    WHERE t1.lastactivity > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '100 days'
```

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is ANSI standard, and works on Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server...

Here's the CREATE table statement converted:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  "from" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  message text NOT NULL,
  lastactivity timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  read INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

I can't find anything about Postgres allowing character sets per table, only that you would set UTF8 support using the UNICODE keyword when creating the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE your_db WITH  ENCODING 'UNICODE';
$ createdb -E UNICODE your_db --CLI version
```

Postgre, like Oracle, uses [sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html) for AUTO_INCREMENT behavior:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE example_seq START 1;
```

Then, you need to call NEXTVAL([your sequence name]) in the insert statement to populate the primary key:

```
INSERT INTO example (id) VALUES (NEXTVAL(example_seq))
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I'm pretty sure the 'serial' data type works well enough for simple id needs, doesn't it?

Comment: @colinmarc: I'm not familiar with the serial data type.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL serial allows you to use DEFAULT or not specify and it will auto-increment. In my tables I always use "id" serial PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is not going to work, it's not a valid timestamp. DEFAULT NULL is allowed.

Comment: Also, now() is preferred to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in PostgreSQL according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: I get this error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 3:   from VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

Comment: The word "from" cannot be a field name

Comment: 'from' is the name of the column - the problem, I think, is that it should be enclosed in quotes because it's also a keyword

Comment: @colinmarc: From your link, all I got was that NOW() is the equivalent to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, not the preferred syntax (which your link is for 8.1 when 8.4 is current).

Comment: You should use double quotes to declare from as a field name

Comment: FROM is a registered keyword - need to use double quotes to escape it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: I agree that the serial type should be used for the ID.  Especially if he's used to MySQL autoincrement.

Comment: "now() is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to transaction_timestamp()" - from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT, the 8.4 documentation.

Comment: @colinmarc: "traditional" != preferred, as you claimed.

Comment: indeed in the "date/time functions" table, it says that now()/transaction_timestamp() is equivalent to current_timestamp- I'd usually use current_timestamp because it's a reasonably well-known standard.

Comment: @xRobot: postgresql will store all text values using the character set that is defined when you create the database (and shown when you do \l in psql)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just post my own answer. Here's your `CREATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE "example" ( 
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,    
  "from" varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',    
  "message" text NOT NULL,    
  "lastactivity" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,    
  "read" integer NOT NULL
);
```

Note that `serial` accomplishes `int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment`, and that `integer` is used instead of `int`. Your query seems fine.